# If we see only the reflected colour, how coloured shadows are of same colour?

Tags: visible-light, reflection, refraction

We know, for instance, if something is blue, it is because it is absorbing all other wavelengths of coloured light and reflecting the blue colour.

But when we pass a white light through a  coloured translucent object, the shadow it forms, contains the hue of the same colour.

If the blue light has been reflected, and absorbed light is everything but blue. Why is it so?

Also, is this phenomena related to some specific number of boundaries and mediums light has to go across?

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer:** the coloured light of the "shadow" *is* reflected.

**More detailed answer:** if we have, say, a blue translucent object, the object only allows blue light to pass through (which is what makes it translucent in a blue colour). If shining a light onto it to create a "shadow", the "shadow" will be formed by an absence of all light except for blue light. The blue light is still free to be reflected off the floor or wall into our eyes, so it appears blue.